# RNCSafeAreaProvider was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-windows

I know that this question has been asked before but all of them are all about `android` or `IOS`
I am having this problem in `react-native-windows`

`"RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager`
Is there any thing I could do about this? I think that the autolinking not working for `react-native-windows`

Here is my Package.JSON

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@alentoma/usestate": "^1.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-windows": "0.67.3"
  },
```